# Why "artillery" is not recognized as an internal or an external command?

Tags: node.js, artillery

I want to use artillery to test a nodejs app,
I installed artillery.io globally and I added the path to the environmen variables, but I still get the error 
*"'artillery' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."*. I can't find similar issues on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't install it in *cmd* first either, but then repeating same installation steps through **Powershell** (run as **Administrator**) worked fine.
Being:

1. install: npm install -g artillery
2. check installation: artillery -V

Answer (score 0):

Look in the folder pointed out by
`$yarn global dir` and see if that folder is in your $PATH.

Or you can specify the a prefix when adding the package like below.

`$yarn global add artillery --prefix /usr/local`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set environment variable path of npm

and my system npm path is "C:\Users\RanjitBarsa\AppData\Roaming\npm"

hope this works!!